# Angular-PHP CORS request blocked

Tags: php, angular

I am trying to send from my angular project an email via a php service at the time a form is filled out.

When I try to send the request in the console
I get the following error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://website/assets/php/mail.php?con_name=user&con_email=mail&con_message=test&con_subject=Hello%20World' from origin 'https://website' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

As advised by many of you within the PHP file I have already unsuccessfully included "header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');" and "header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');"

The angular call is:

```
sendMail() {
    
    this.mailValidator()
    if(this.validate() && this.mailValidator() )
    {
      this.http.get("https://website.com/assets/php/mail.php?con_name="+this.name+"&con_email="+this.email+"&con_message="+this.message+"&con_subject="+this.object).subscribe((val) => {
      
      })
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
 
  }
```

The PHP code is

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
echo("Test")

?>
```

Comment: Which web server are you using and do u know how to configure it in general?

Comment: The site is hosted on Aruba (https://www.aruba.it/home.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try adding allow the Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin and see if that helps you ?

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: I always get the same error

Comment: do you call the api from your localhost ?

Comment: No, I've built the project and published it on the hosting service, currently I'm just changing the php file with every example I can find in the web

Comment: did you restart/hard refresh your server (apache server) so the changes take place.
if this didn't work , then you can try adapting the create the .htaccess and add the following line to it Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin * , then please refresh your server too

Comment: No, I cannot restart the Apache server as I am using a hosting service (Aruba). Instead, the .htaccess file is not currently present within the angular project. I provide with its creation and insert the commands you sent me? If I create it, is it ok to place it in the same path where angular.json is located?